# Python module not found (directory problems)

Tags: python, python-2.5

I have a Python 2.5 project with following directory structure:

```
database/__init__.py
database/createDBConnection.py
gui/mainwindow.py
```

When I try to run

```
python gui/mainwindow.py
```

I get the error

```
C:\PopGen>python gui/mainwindow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui/mainwindow.py", line 12, in <module>
    from database.createDBConnection import createDBC
ImportError: No module named database.createDBConnection
```

In mainwindow.py, there is following statement on line 12

```
from database.createDBConnection import createDBC
```

The problem occurs because Python can't find the database module.

Question: What can I do in order to fix this error?

Here's the code of the project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/edfutlba960atp9/MwFpaepEpl

I tried to use

```
C:\PopGen>python -m gui.mainwindow
```

but got these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 95, in run_module
    filename, loader, alter_sys)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 52, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\runpy.py", line 32, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\PopGen\gui\mainwindow.py", line 13, in <module>
    from file_menu.wizard_window_validate import Wizard
ImportError: No module named file_menu.wizard_window_validate
```

Comment: What does your python path look like?  Also, check for circular imports.

Comment: C:\Python25 (it's included in the %PATH% environment variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this, but this is perhaps the easiest one.

Try adding this in mainwindow.py, prior to the import that is failing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/path/to/database/module")
```